# Отправка данных из приложения или UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, activity, text

Создал я `@IBAction`, в котором прописал `UIActivityViewController`.

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let text1 = "Перевод величины Годы в количестве \(year) лет."
        let text2 = "Месяцы: \(mounthLabel.text!)"
        let text3 = "Недели: \(weekLabel.text!)"
        let text4 = "Дни: \(dayLabel.text!)"
        let text5 = "Часы: \(hourLabel.text!)"
        let text6 = "Минуты: \(minuteLabel.text!)"
        let text7 = "Секунды: \(secundLabel.text!)"
        let URL0 = "Скачать конвертер величин по ссылке:"
        let URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unit-converter/id1329406653?l=ru&ls=1&mt=8"
        let space = ""
        let space2 = ""


        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text1, space, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, space2, URL0, URL], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Все замечательно работает, однако при экспорте в приложение штатное "Заметки" сохраняет только первую строку `text1`. Что может быть не так и есть ли способ это исправить?

Comment: UPD. В Вконтакте он отправляет полный текст. В сообщения тоже. Мессенджеры и Фейсбук так же пишут только 1-ую строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй так:

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let text1 = "Перевод величины Годы в количестве \(year) лет."
    let text2 = "Месяцы: \(mounthLabel.text!)"
    let text3 = "Недели: \(weekLabel.text!)"
    let text4 = "Дни: \(dayLabel.text!)"
    let text5 = "Часы: \(hourLabel.text!)"
    let text6 = "Минуты: \(minuteLabel.text!)"
    let text7 = "Секунды: \(secundLabel.text!)"
    let URL0 = "Скачать конвертер величин по ссылке:"
    let URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unit-converter/id1329406653?l=ru&ls=1&mt=8"

    let allText = text1 + "\n" + text2 + "\n" + text3 + "\n" + text4 + "\n" + text5 + "\n" + text6 + "\n" + text7 + "\n" +  URL0 + "\n" + URL
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [allText], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```